# How to fix an 'inlining failed in call to always_inline '__builtin_alloca'' error when building GCC for Windows

Tags: gcc

I'm building GCC 8.3.0 for Windows 10, using msys, and the build fails with the following error:

```
gcc -c -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g  -I. -I../../source/libiberty/../include  -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wc++-compat -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshadow=local -pedantic  -D_GNU_SOURCE ../../source/libiberty/pex-win32.c -o pex-win32.o
In file included from ../../source/libiberty/pex-common.h:25,
                 from ../../source/libiberty/pex-win32.c:21:
c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\alloca.h: In function 'win32_spawn':
../../source/libiberty/../include/libiberty.h:722:20: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline '__builtin_alloca': function not considered for inlining
 # define alloca(x) __builtin_alloca(x)
                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\stdlib.h:499,
                 from c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\objbase.h:12,
                 from c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\ole2.h:9,
                 from c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\windows.h:100,
                 from ../../source/libiberty/pex-win32.c:23:
c:\software-development\prebuilt\mingw32\include\alloca.h:62:48: note: called from here
 __CRT_ALIAS void *alloca( size_t __n ){ return __builtin_alloca( __n ); }
```

Is there a sensible way to fix this error in configuration, or failing, this, some way to patch or work around this issue?

Here is my current configuration, ran from a batch file:

```
--prefix=/c/software-development/gcc-8.3.0/install-x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
--build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
--enable-shared \
--enable-static \
--enable-bootstrap \
--enable-languages=c,c++,lto
```

The same error occurred when building gcc 8.2.0, and with the build guessed. I'm using GNU's MinGW 8.2.0 to build.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping everywhere in the libiberty.h file "__builtin_alloca" on "C_alloca". Replacement in one place. In preprocessor commands. It helped me.